# SQL Query where condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a record which has the following data:
    id=123 ;
    requested_by=Jackson ;
    verify_status=NULL ;

i wish the record above as the result for the following query. However, it returns me 0 row.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM spr WHERE requested_by IS NOT NULL AND verify_status!='Accept'";
```

I wanna select all records which the verify_status other than "Accept".

I wonder is there something wrong with verify_status!='Accept'? Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle those rows with a `NULL` `verify_status`:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM spr WHERE requested_by IS NOT NULL 
       AND (verify_status IS NULL OR verify_status != 'Accept'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any comparison against `NULL` is false, so `NULL` fields have to be handled explicitly.

You can either do it with an or-

`where verify_status is null or verify_status != 'Accept'`

Or, you can use `coalesce` to transform `NULL` into a different value

`where coalesce(verify_status, 'xxNULLxx') != 'Accept'`

(Note that using a function, such a `coalesce` in this manner makes it so that your query can't use any indexes that are on `verify_status`.